# Getting 405 status instead of expected 200 in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rack, ruby-grape

I am writing a test for my Grape API which is mounted in a Rack app. I am making a simple GET request in this test, but it is giving me a 405 status code instead of the expected 200.

Here is the spec:

```
require 'grape'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rack/test'
require './api/api/app'

describe API::App do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    API::App
  end

  describe API::App do
    describe "GET /users" do
      it "retrieves users" do
        get "/users"
        expect(last_response.status).to eq(200)
        expect(JSON.parse(last_response.body)).to eq []
      end
    end   
  end
end
```

It seems that it does not understand the method i am using, in this case GET. Why does it not recognize it?

Answer (score -1):

Try making this a request spec:

```
describe API::App, type: :request do
  # your code
end
```

so that you get access to helper methods such as `get`. [Further reading](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec).